# Can app signing by Google Play save me if I haven't yet opted in?

Tags: android, android-app-signing

I have an old app that I haven't updated in a few years. I went to update it and realized the keystore is nowhere to be found.

If I choose to opt in to app signing by Google Play now - can that save me? I know once you've opted in, if you lose your upload keystore, you can request it to be replaced. But I'm not sure if I can make such a request with my initial opting in.

Comment: AFAIK, Not possible to maintain your Play Store App listing. You can change the package name and opt-in, which is like submitting a completely new app. All the downloads, reviews, ratings, etc are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the original keystore and without Play Signing, there is nothing you can do but create a new app (i.e. a new package name).

It is not possible to enroll in Play Signing without the original keystore.